# Named query not found: UnescalatedStartDeadlines (on trivial workflow)

Tags: jbpm

I am an old hand at JBPM but while coding stuff in JBPM 7.41 experiencing

```
17:28:47.622 [main] DEBUG o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JTA transaction was already joined (RegisteredSynchronization already registered)
17:28:47.626 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
17:28:47.628 [main] ERROR o.j.s.t.c.InitDeadlinesCommand - Error when executing deadlines
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [UnescalatedStartDeadlines]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:807
```

on a trivial process - just a script logging that it has been reached in between start and end nodes - coded in Java and running under Wildfly.  I read that this comes from an issue with persistence.xml and several ORM files, but I am not using human tasks, custom work item handlers, etc.  I also don't find any ORM files in the BusinessCentral.war nor in KieServer.war.  Do I need Taskorm.xml and jbpmorm.xml for this trivial example?  I've read that these come in  jbpm-human-task-jpa.jar , but I don't find that JAR when I explode either war.  Could someone show where I should be looking if I need to modify these xml files?  Thx in advance!

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testDS1</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Content</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Delegation</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Escalation</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Group</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.I18NText</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Notification</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotification</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotificationHeader</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.PeopleAssignments</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Reassignment</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Status</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.Task</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.TaskData</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.SubTasksStrategy</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.OnParentAbortAllSubTasksEndStrategy</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.OnAllSubTasksEndParentEndStrategy</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.task.User</class>
 <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${maven.hibernate.dialect}"/>
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="${maven.jdbc.schema}"/>

      <!-- BZ 841786: AS7/EAP 6/Hib 4 uses new (sequence) generators which seem to cause problems -->
      <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.handling_mode" value="DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I found JBPMorm.xml and taskorm.xml, added them to src/main/resources but still getting the following.  I will try to add my persistence.xml as an attachment. 
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [UnescalatedStartDeadlines]

Comment: I can see that UnescalatedStartDeadlines is in Taskorm.xml.  For my trivial program, I will add jbpm-human-task.jar as a dependency, even though I am not using any human tasks, and see if that solves the issue.